# Using jquery to find the number of characters in img src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, src

I have image slider:

```html
<ul class="slider">
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
  <li><img src=""></li>
</ul>
```

If the length of characters is `<=41` , I want to remove the `li` tag. I tried the following code but its not working

```
var li = $(".slider ul > li");
var $img = $(".slider > ul > li img").attr("src");
if ($img == length(41)) {
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will do it:

```
$(".slider > ul > li img").filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('src').length <= 41;
}).closest('li').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".slider ul li").each(function(){
    var imgsrclength = $(this).find("img").attr("src").length;
    if (parseInt(imgsrclength) >= 41) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```